# Add menu element on right click on taskbar

Tags: lxde, openbox, pcmanfm, lxpanel

I am using `openbox` with `lxpanel` and `pcmanfm`. Not sure what program handle that right click on the `TaskBar`.

I would like to add an element to the menu and execute a specific command. (`wmctrl` or `xdotool` to make the window `"stay on top"`)

Comment: I'm talking about the right clic on the taskbar. (Close window, minimize, maximize, move to workspace...)